# UIImageView setFrame

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Hi I came across this piece of code and I was wondering what setFrame was. I couldn't find it in the UIImageView docs.

`[largeImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x_o, y_o, width, height)];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is setting the `frame` property using the method syntax rather than the dotted notation.  The `frame` is a property of all `UIView` objects (not just `UIImageView`), and is a rectangle that defines the view's location and size in terms of the parent view's co-ordinate system.

It is defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame
```

Contrast `frame` with `bounds`, which is a rect in the view's own co-ordinate system.  Normally `frame` is derived from `bounds`.

View geometry, frames and bounds are explained in detail here:

- [View Geometry and Coordinate Systems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5)

The class reference is here:

- [UIView class reference - frame property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame)